# How to control windows-ce 5.0 backlight?

Tags: c#, windows-ce

Is there a way to control to a windows-ce 5.0 tablet device (DAP CE8800) backlight (dim/bright) programatically using C#?

Comment: Glad you found a solution!  It would actually make more sense for you to post it as the answer instead of editing the question, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out DAP does support backlight control on this tablet. I was able to get it to work by adding DapServiceCS.dll and this code:

```
DsLightSensor lightSensor = new DsLightSensor();
if (DapServices.DS_EXECUTION_OK ==
    DapServices.DapService(DapServicesCode.DS_GET_LIGHT_SENSOR, lightSensor))
{
    lightSensor.dwIntensity = hScrollBarIntensity.Value;
    DapServices.DapService(DapServicesCode.DS_SET_LIGHT_SENSOR, lightSensor);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard OS-defined mechanism for backlight operation (intensity or active/inactive).  Those devices that do have programmatic control (and not all do) use proprietary APIs.  Sometimes it's a driver call, sometimes a developer API, and sometimes it's more esoteric (like a CPL call).

I'm not readily seeing any sort of SDK download on [the OEM's product page](http://www.daptech.com/products/M8800), so your best bet is going to be to contact them directly and ask.

Comment: From the OEM: `You should be able to use the _MSC applet to set the Function key as a hot key. You will then point it to the backlight control applet in the control panel by browsing to  \Windows and typed "DapAdvBacklight.cpl"`

Comment: Yeah, so their answer is, in a nutshell, "no we don't support that."